# Вызов замыкания через статическое свойство

Tags: php, замыкания

Почему возникает ошибка, если я пытаюсь вызвать замыкание(анонимную функцию), которое хранится в статическом свойстве объекта?

```
return self::$container();
```

Notice: Undefined variable: container

Fatal error: Function name must be a string

В то время как:

```
return $this->container();
```

отработает корректно, при условии что $container является public, конечно-же.

Приходится писать:

```
$closure = self::$container;
return $closure();
```

Либо:

```
return self::$container->__invoke();
```

Почему так? В чём загвоздка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я могу ошибаться, но по моему мнению PHP интерпретирует данный скрипт так:

```
return self::$container();
```

PHP считает, что $container - название функции в переменной и её нужно подставить.
Но вот незадача! $container не задана!

Т.е. если бы было..

```
$container = "_test";
return self::$container(); //исполнялось бы self::_test();
```

На этой же фишке работает данный код:

```
$test = "testVar";
$$test = "Some text";
echo $testVar; //Some text
```

Естественно я могу ошибаться. Но вот как то так.

Comment: нет, не считает, просто он очень неконсистентный язык

Comment: @Etki документация [подтверждает](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php) корректность ответа.

Comment: @Sergiks а, понял. Попутал переменную со свосйтвом (что, в общем, тоже летит в копилку неконсистентности)